# Python scripts not finishing when run as cronjob

Tags: python-3.x, cron

We have multiple scripts running on a CentOS 6.10 server.

We use both Python 2.6 and 3.4 (2.6 is for older scripts that have not yet been ported).

When a script is run manually in terminal it completes it task just fine.

If its run via cronjob it just exits partway through its process.

Here is an example of two cronjobs that exit partway through.

```
40 16 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /opt/chile/call_collect_stats/bin/app.py `/bin/date --date '1 day ago' +\%Y\%m\%d` `/bin/date --date '1 day ago' +\%Y\%m\%d` >/dev/null 2>&1
50 17 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /opt/chile/call_collect_stats/bin/reconciler.py `/bin/date --date '1 day ago' +\%Y\%m\%d` `/bin/date --date '1 day ago' +\%Y\%m\%d` >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Script needs two dates (first and last date to process) hence why `date` is passed to it twice to run it against yesterday's data.

This has happened before and redirecting `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to `/dev/null` sorted that out, however now its not helping.

Comment: I just realized I posted this question on SO when I meant to post it on SU or SF.